# Powershell Wrong output

Tags: powershell

**guys i need help here, i want to return the $Location002 and $Location003 content** look what is in output

```
$Location = "westus2"
$Location002 = "westeurope"
$Location003 = "eastasia"

[int]$VMCount = Read-Host "How many VMs?"

1..$VMCount | ForEach-Object {
    
    $i = $_

    # define name for VM, will be used for other resources
    if ($i -eq 1) {
        $locname = "$Location"
        Write-Output $locname
    }
    else {
        $locname = $("Location00" + "$i")
        Write-Output $locname 
    }
}
```

***output :***

```
PS C:\Users\Marouane\Desktop\testpowershell> c:\Users\Marouane\Desktop\testpowershell\test.ps1
How many VMs?: 3
westus2
Location002
Location003
PS C:\Users\Marouane\Desktop\testpowershell>
```

i need to output **westeurope** and **eastasia**

Comment: You don't have a `$Location003` for starters...

Comment: it's just  a miss i edited the code.

what I want is to return the content of the $Location002 and $Location003 with the loop that I created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how I would do it, but the more immediate problem is you're assigning a concatenated string to `$location` and writing to the output stream.  I think what you want to do is reference the value of the earlier variable.

There are some clever syntaxes for that.  I struggle to remember them.  However below would be a start.

```
$Location = "westus2"
$Location002 = "westeurope"
$Location003 = "eastasia"

[int]$VMCount = Read-Host "How many VMs?"

1..$VMCount | ForEach-Object {
    
    $i = $_

    # define name for VM, will be used for other resources
    if ($i -eq 1) {
        $name = "$VMName"
        $locname = "$Location"
        Write-Output $locname
    }
    else {
        $name = "$VMName" + "00" + "$i"
        $locname = (Get-Variable ("Location00" + "$i")).Value
        Write-Output $locname 
    }
}
```

**Update With Alternative:**

I'm still not sure what the goal is, but based on the original sample it would seem there's a 1 to 1 relationship between the location# and the VM number.  That said if you go past the number of VMs you would have to adjust this to pick according to the intended pattern...

```
$Locations = 'westus2', 'westeurope', 'eastasia'
    
[int]$VMCount = Read-Host 'How many VMs?'

For( $i = 0; $i -lt $VMCount ; ++$i )
{
    $Locations[$i]
}
```

**Further Update:**

Respective to [Mathias's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64613949/4749264) :

```
$Locations = 'westus2', 'westeurope', 'eastasia'

[int]$VMCount = Read-Host 'How many VMs?'

For( $i = 0; $i -lt $VMCount ; ++$i )
{
    $Locations[ $i % $Locations.Count ]
}
```

Using the modulus operator in this pattern is very efficient for distributing one list over another.  I wrote a small post about [My Modulus Obsession](https://posh-able.com/2021/05/17/my-modulus-obsession/) with this and some other uses.

Answer (score 1):

Using a separate variable for each value in a group or list of things is a bit of an anti-pattern, you'll want to put them all in an array together instead:

```
# Define array of possible locations
# `$Locations[0]` will resolve to `westus2`
# `$Locations[1]` will resolve to `westeurope`, etc.
$Locations = @(
  "westus2"
  "westeurope"
  "eastasia"
)

[int]$VMCount = Read-Host "How many VMs?"

1..$VMCount | ForEach-Object {
  # Define the VM name 
  $name = "VirtualMachine$_"

  # Pick next location from the $Locations array
  # the % ensures we "wrap around" when we reach the end
  $location = $Locations[($_ - 1) % $Locations.Length]

  # Output a new object with Name + Chosen Location
  [pscustomobject]@{
    VMName   = $name
    Location = $location
  }
}
```

Output for 3 VMs:

```
How many VMs?: 3

VMName          Location
------          --------
VirtualMachine1 westus2
VirtualMachine2 westeurope
VirtualMachine3 eastasia
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to retrieve the variable's content with `Get-Variable`. You can also avoid the extra step of making an `$i` variable and instead use the automatic variable `$_`

```
$Location = "westus2"
$Location002 = "westeurope"
$Location003 = "eastasia"

[int]$VMCount = Read-Host "How many VMs?"

1..$VMCount | ForEach-Object {

    # define name for VM, will be used for other resources
    if ($_ -eq 1) {
        $name = "$VMName"
        $locname = "$Location"
        Write-Output $locname
    }
    else {
        $name = "$VMName" + "00" + "$_"
        $locname = "Location00" + "$_"
        Write-Output (get-variable $locname).value
    }
}
```